# Question about AddressSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL ==32==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: SEGV on unknown address 0x60211e45f6f0 (leetcode problem))

Tags: c++, pointers, memory

## This is my code about leetcode question 4. and i got
AddressSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL

==32==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: SEGV on unknown address 0x60211e45f6f0 (pc 0x000000345610 bp 0x7ffc47917a90 sp 0x7ffc47917a20 T0)
==32==The signal is caused by a READ memory access.
#2 0x7f228fd230b2  (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x270b2)
AddressSanitizer can not provide additional info.
==32==ABORTING

```
class Solution {
public:
    double findMedianSortedArrays(vector<int>& nums1, vector<int>& nums2) {
        int n1 = nums1.size();
        int n2 = nums2.size();
        int i, j= 0;
        int ans1, ans2;
        for (int counter = 0; counter <= (n1+n2)/2; counter++){
            ans2 = ans1;
            if (i != n1 && j != n2){
                if (nums1[i] < nums2[j]){
                    ans1 = nums1[i];
                    i++;
                }
                else {
                    ans1 = nums2[j];
                    j++;
                }
            }
            else if(i < n1){
                ans1 = nums1[i];
                i++;
            }
            else {
                ans1 = nums2[j];
                j++;
            }
        }
        if((n1+n2) % 2 == 1){
            double ans = (double)ans1;
            return ans;
        }
        else {
            return (ans1 + ans2)/2.00000;
        }

    }
};
```

Comment: Compile your code on your computer and turn on the sanitizers and crank up the warnings and you too can get helpful warnings of incorrect code. Eg: https://godbolt.org/z/vcPro4aqT That's a different failure case, mind you. The point is test the code thoroughly with all of the tools at your disposal before submitting it.

Comment: `i` is uninitialized. `int i, j= 0;` only initializes `j` to `0`.